# What is the equivalent in React of jQuery(text).find('[data-char]')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to migrate angular/jquery project to React but I don't know how can I have an equivalent to

```
var text = "<p><span class="mention" data-index="1" data-char="@" data-id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000000" data-value="Jhon Doe" data-target="jhon.doe@gmail.com"><span class="ql-mention-char">@</span>Jhon Doe</span> </p><p><br></p><p>azeaz </p><p>azeazea</p><p>zeaze</p>
<span class="mention" data-index="1" data-char="@" data-id="00100000-0010-0100-0100-0001-10000100000001" data-value="Jhonny Tommy" data-target="jhonny.tommy@gmail.com"><span class="ql-mention-char">@</span>Jhonny Tommy</span>"

jQuery().find('[data-char]')
```

at least what i want to do is get all `data-id` in a table

Comment: Why you can't use jQuery with react?

Comment: @Justinas because for me both don't work it's not in React concept, that's why i want an alternative and i explain what I wanted to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React, we usually prefer to store data in the state of the component and render the UI based on that state. We try to avoid direct DOM manipulations that jQuery usually does.

We can use `DOMParser` to parse the HTML string into a Document. Then using `querySelectorAll` we can select all the elements with a `data-char` attribute.
After getting the elements, we can convert them to an array, map over the elements, and extract the `data-id` for each element. The ids are then set into a `useState` with `setIds` and rendered.

Try this one -->

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function YourComponent() {
  const [ids, setIds] = useState([]);
  const htmlText = `<p><span class="mention" data-index="1" data-char="@" data-id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000000" data-value="Jhon Doe" data-target="jhon.doe@gmail.com"><span class="ql-mention-char">@</span>Jhon Doe</span> </p><p><br></p><p>azeaz </p><p>azeazea</p><p>zeaze</p>
<span class="mention" data-index="1" data-char="@" data-id="00100000-0010-0100-0100-0001-10000100000001" data-value="Jhonny Tommy" data-target="jhonny.tommy@gmail.com"><span class="ql-mention-char">@</span>Jhonny Tommy</span>`;

  useEffect(() => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(htmlText, 'text/html');

    const mentions = htmlDoc.querySelectorAll('[data-char]');
    const dataIds = Array.from(mentions).map(mention => mention.dataset.id);
    setIds(dataIds);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {ids.map((id, index) => <p key={index}>{id}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default YourComponent;
```